# How Vedic philosophy and Puranic philosophy related with each other?

Tags: vedas, puranas, vedanta, rig-veda, vedic-gods

**Aditi (Vedas) referred to Shakti (Puranas) :**

Aditi is mentioned as Devamata (Mother of all God's) and Adi Parashakti is mentioned as Mahadevi (Mother/Goddess of all God's)

**Hiranyagarbha (Vedas) referred to Brahma (Puranas):**

Hiranyagarbha in Veda and Brahma in Puranas both are the first being and creator of Universe, space, time, etc.

Hiranyagarbha is also mentioned as Prajapati in Vedas.

**Visnu (Vedas) referred to Vishnu (Puranas):**

Visnu in Veda mentioned as greater one and in Puranas Vishnu is mentioned as Preserver, Sustainer and Operator.

Vishnu is also mentioned as Narayana & Hari in Puranas and Vamana in Vedas

**Siva (Vedas) referred to Shiva (Puranas):**

Siva in Vedas mentioned as Auspicious and in Puranas Shiva is mentioned as Destroyer, Transformer and Re-generator.

In Vedas Siva is also mentioned as Tryambaka, Rudra, Ishana & Sadasiva and in Puranas Shiva is mentioned as Mahadev, Mahakaal, Parashiva, Bholenaath, etc

**Indra (Vedas) referred to Indra (Puranas):**

Indra in Vedas mentioned as King of All God and Governance of universe and in Puranas Indra is mentioned as King of Svarga loka (Heaven), Even some Puranas says Indra is not being but a positions.

**Questions :**

1. Correct me if i am wrong at any place?
2. Why do peoples think the Gods in Vedas are totally different from God in Puranas?
3. Why do Indra (Vedas) superior God demoted as Demi-God in Puranas and Later, In Geeta Indra demoted to Position/Post. (And this same happen to Brahma)

**Note :** Please give the answer being unbiased not as sectarian.

Comment: The answer cannot be given from the position of non-sectarianism. According to the Srautas, there is no Ishvara in the Vedic Samhitas. They interpret the Purusha Sukta along with other suktas, not higher. For them, Purusha is a god along with Indra, Varuna, Rudra, Vishnu, etc. From the position of Vaishnavas and Shaivites, Purusha Sukta indicates Ishvara, and which Ishvara is specified in Narayana Sukta or Rudra Sukta, in their opinion. According to science, the Srautas are right - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Arauta

Comment: @sadhaka108 i got your point. It fine to be sectarians. What you feel about my observation about Vedas and Puranas.

Comment: Even if you ignore all the Vedas, Itihasas and Puranas, then Vaishnavism and Shaivism will feel great due to the fact that Agamas / Tantras exist. For example, all Shaivite sampradayas that exist today are mainly based on the Tantras and Granthas of their Acharyas, and the texts of Shruti and Smriti for Shaivas are only optional.